# How can I change number of days to date?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, date

How can I change number of days to date in sql server 2008 ?

- Sample days : `730677`.
- Output : `2000-07-11`.

Comment: "Number of days to date"??? If i use `SELECT DATEADD(day, 730677, 0)` i get year 3900, i doubt that this is what you want.

Comment: What You want to do ?

Comment: @TimSchmelter: I think he means starting from 01/01/0000

Comment: Does this number of days express a number of days from a specific date? for example number of days from today date

Comment: @musefan: then it's still 3900(changed my comment above)

Comment: @TimSchmelter: That doesn't seem right... `730677 / 365.25 = 2000.48` ... that however doesn't factor in leap years with complete accuracy, but it's not far off

Comment: Write a query to get the DATE value from a given day (number in N). Go to the editor
Sample days : 730677
Output : 2000-07-11

Comment: @TimSchmelter: That will give you the number of years (roughly because of leap year). It really need to account for skipping leap years every 100 year (but still leap every 400 years) though... I imagine SQL has minimum workable date of 1900 (which is why you get 3900 as a result)

Comment: @musefan: of course, sql-server date starts with 1/1/1753 not with 0/0/0000

Answer (score 6):

You have a problem,

The earliest date represented by a SQL Sever [`DateTime2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335.aspx) is `'0001-01-01'`

As we can see that is 366 days after your "epoch start"

```
SELECT 730677 - DATEDIFF(
        day,
        CAST('0001-01-01' AS DATETIME2),
        CAST('2000-07-11' AS DATETIME2));
```

To perform your calculation you could do something like

```
DECLARE @days INT = 730677;

SELECT DATEADD(day, @days - 366, CAST('0001-01-01' AS DATETIME2));
```

If you need to represent days earlier than 366, you will need an alternative.